# Unable to load mod_cdr_pg_csv module in Freeswitch

Tags: postgresql, freeswitch, debian-jessie

New Freeswitch installation Debian Jessie 8 in AWS:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
```

Using Installation instructions from [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie).

```
wget -O - https://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/debian/freeswitch_archive_g0.pub | apt-key add -

echo "deb http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6/ jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freeswitch.list

# you may want to populate /etc/freeswitch at this point.
# if /etc/freeswitch does not exist, the standard vanilla configuration is deployed
apt-get update && apt-get install -y freeswitch-meta-all
```

Following instructions for `mod_cdr_pg_csv` [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_cdr_pg_csv) I have installed:

```
apt-get install libpq-dev libpq5
apt-get install postgresql-client
```

But still unable to load module or find it.

```
>module_exists mod_cdr_pg_csv
false


>load mod_cdr_pg_csv
+OK Reloading XML
-ERR [module load file routine returned an error]

2018-02-10 08:59:30.427543 [INFO] mod_enum.c:879 ENUM Reloaded
2018-02-10 08:59:30.427543 [INFO] switch_time.c:1423 Timezone reloaded 1750 definitions
2018-02-10 08:59:30.427543 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1522 Error Loading module /usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_cdr_pg_csv.so
**/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_cdr_pg_csv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

Debug freeswitch.log

```
2018-02-10 07:47:01.012683 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1522 Error Loading module /usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_cdr_pg_csv.so
**/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_cdr_pg_csv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

`modules.conf.xml` has been configured.

When I run `find / -name "mod_cdr_pg_csv.so"` I don't get any result.

Still unable to load module. 
Another module like mod_python successfully loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up re-installing Freeswitch using different instructions.

1. [Install](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/) Postgres dependencies
2. [Building From Source Compiling Release Branch (production)](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie) and run Freeswitch installation using the following flag:

   ./configure --enable-core-pgsql-support